# Java Swing Generate JTable from POJO at runtime

Tags: java, swing, automation, jtable

I'm looking for a library able to build at runtime, using some configuration (xml, annotations, ...) and reflection, a complete JTable (model + searchable and sortable jtable) from a collection of POJOS.

I did not found anything like that on the web and I'm wondering if something already exist before I start to coding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project that sounds the most similar to your requirements is [GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/). It provides filtering instead of searching - and there's not really any configuration - it's just an API that provides `TableModel`/`ListModel` implementations that wrap your POJO collections.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simple but useful **BeanPropertyTableModel** class from [swingtools](http://code.google.com/p/swingtools/) project that uses reflection in order to generate a JTable Model. There are some configuration methods for setting field orders, localizing field names, etc. See [this blog post](http://www.ipsoftware.ru/blog/?p=10).

```
List<Account> accounts = ...
BeanPropertyTableModel<Account> model = new BeanPropertyTableModel<Account>(Account.class);
model.setOrderedProperties(Arrays.asList("name", "host", "user", "password"));
model.setData(accounts);
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```